# How to get acess token from ServiceStack API

Tags: servicestack

I'm using the service stack core 4 with Identity template, https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcidentity, and have added the following:

```
    new CredentialsAuthProvider(AppSettings),
```

to the AuthFeature set.

Also

```
var userRepo = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRepo);
```

I then try the following POST request:
http://localhost:53486/auth/credentials
with a body of:

```
{
    "UserName": "admin@gmail.com",
    "Password": "p@55wOrd"
}
```

and get an **Invalid Username or Password**.

The template works via the web ui but I cannot get api request to work.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

When you're using the [mvcidentity](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcidentity) you're **not** using [ServiceStack Authentication](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization), you're electing to use [ASP.NET Core's Identity Auth](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-identity-aspnet) instead so you'd need to Authenticate with ASP.NET's Identity Auth API's like the [Login() method on the AccountController](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcidentity/blob/365a1d0637312433ec5fc735e30bb0d134aa4400/MyApp/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L65):

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(LoginWith2fa), new { returnUrl, model.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout));
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

If you want to use **ServiceStack Auth with MVC** instead you should start from the [mvcauth .NET Core Template](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcauth) which is the same application, but configured to use [ServiceStack Auth](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization) instead.

Comment: I think i've not made myself clear. I am using postman to test the api features of service stack. I dont want to use the "Login()" method as there is no user and only another application wanting to get an access token to call the api  endpoints that are restricted. This is why I'm trying the HTTP POST call to the /auth/credentials url.

Comment: @StephenCossgrove Ok but since you've chosen to use MVC Identity Auth you can't use ServiceStack Auth's built-in APIs and would need to provide your own Controllers/Methods that utilizes MVC's Identity Auth APIs. Best to start with one of the [many Identity Auth examples on the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=asp+.net+identity+auth+jwt) like [ASP.NET Core 3.1 - JWT Authentication Tutorial with Example API](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/11/aspnet-core-3-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api)